# Function delaying of chosen part of the site (php, js, ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, timeout, delay

Does exists function which delayed the load the selected section of the page?

In page I have two div's:

```
<div id="slider">
   <!-- large amount of code -->
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
   <!-- small amount of code -->
</div>
```

Is it possible to placing the first div in some php functions to load up after reading this second?

Or is there a some delay function? Meaby put the div#slider in a separate file? (sliders is hidden click on the pictures starts it).

```
<?php include('slider.php'); ?>

<div id="thumbs">
   <!-- small amount of code -->
</div>
```

For example:

Lets say I have gallery: [Gallery image](http://localhostr.com/file/vzPj8qe/slider.png)

When I clicked on image, slider are extends (with slides for this thumb): [slider](http://localhostr.com/file/ZG2kZhS/gallery.png)

I want that the gallery of pictures to load as first (div #thumbs) and later part with sliders (in background).

Comment: You mean like doing AJAX in `onLoad()`?

Comment: If you explain what are you trying to do. May this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand the question correctly, you would have to use js (ajax) for that.

I use jquery library for handling that.

You can do something like this:

Have this load first on the page:

```
<div id="thumbs">
   <!-- small amount of code -->
</div>
```

and then in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
          var slider = $('<div>',{id: 'slider'}).load('slider.php');
          $('#thumbs').before(slider);
     }, 5000); //load after 5 seconds
})
```

Comment: It is good solution but unfortunately not in my case (slider stops working).

Exists some function for php include? like timeout, delay or something?

`<?php  include('slider.php'); ?>`

Comment: In that case I will try rebuild whole slider with used your solution. Thank you.